SPO and Site Collection Policies
quick question :
Does the site collection feature "Site Collection Policies" still exists in SharePoint Online ? I see "Site Policy", but my client says that it differs, and I am not familiar with this feature, although I remember seeing it on SharePoint Server.
Thank you

Differences Between "Site Collection Policies" and "Site Policies":

Site Collection Policies (SharePoint Server):

It allowed you to define and enforce various governance policies at the site collection level. It included policies related to content types, information management policies, and retention schedules.
It was a more centralised and a way more powerful governance tool than in SPO.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/site-policy-overview
This feature exists only partly in SharePoint Online. Its functionality has been either deprecated or replaced by other features.
I have been trying to find an image for you, but the internet fails me :)
Have a look here: https://aimp2.apec.org/_layouts/help.aspx?cid=MS.OSS.manifest&tid=MS.OSS.HA10099553&lcid=1033

Site Policy (SharePoint Online):

Allows you to define rules around the life-cycle of a site (e.g., automatic closure, deletion after a period of inactivity, or manual closure and deletion).

Alternatives in SharePoint Online:

Retention Policies (Compliance Center/Purview): set retention policies and labels that apply across SharePoint Online, Exchange, Teams, and OneDrive.
Information Management Policies: applied at the document library level or to content types in SharePoint Online.
Data Loss Prevention (DLP)
Sensitivity Labels
a bit old but Classification: https://powershellscripts.github.io/articles/en/InformationProtection/Your%20SharePoint%20Online%20site%20classification%20with%20PnP/

Generally, on a global scale, I would say Purview is your friend here.

Thanks a lot, it is clear in my head now.
